# Windows phone application crash when searching for location

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I've got following function:

```
private async void SearchLocation(string location)
    {
        var myPosition = await new Geolocator().GetGeopositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        // Define search
        var geoQuery = new GeocodeQuery();
        geoQuery.SearchTerm = location;
        geoQuery.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(myPosition.Coordinate.Latitude, myPosition.Coordinate.Longitude);
        geoQuery.QueryCompleted += (s, f) =>
        {
            if (f.Error == null && f.Result.Count > 0)
            {
                map.Center = f.Result[0].GeoCoordinate;
                map.ZoomLevel = 12;
            }
        };

        geoQuery.QueryAsync();
    }
```

It's searching for location and show it on map. That works fine, but when I'm clicking on map, my application crashes (map_Tap is empty).
In output appears:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

Stack trace:

```
>   Notifier.DLL!gpsNotifier.App.Application_UnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 112    C#
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.Error.CallApplicationUEHandler(System.Exception e)    Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.Error.IsNonRecoverableUserException(System.Exception ex, out uint xresultValue)   Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(System.IntPtr unmanagedObj, System.IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, int argsTypeIndex, int actualArgsTypeIndex, string eventName)    Unknown
```

I don't understand anything. Exceptions in Visual studio are hard to analyze, because they don't show where the error occured. What's wrong with my function? I'm executing it in button by using SearchLocation("Warsaw");

Edit:
Before SearchLocatio I'm calling another function:

```
private async void ShowMyLocationOnTheMap()
    {
        Geolocator myGeolocator = new Geolocator();
        Geoposition myGeoposition = await myGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
        Geocoordinate myGeocoordinate = myGeoposition.Coordinate;
        GeoCoordinate myGeoCoordinate =
            CoordinateConverter.ConvertGeocoordinate(myGeocoordinate);
        this.map.Center = myGeoCoordinate;
        this.map.ZoomLevel = 15;
        currentLocation.coordinates = myGeoCoordinate;            

    }
```

Comment: Check the exception's `StackTrace` property.

Comment: I don't understand. How?

Comment: Look at the exception object in the debugger (in the locals window or the popup)

Comment: Found this: "Additional information: Cannot change ItemCollection during a OnItemsChanged event.". But I'm not using any collection here.

Comment: `I'm not using any collection here` - apparently something does ...

Comment: Look at the stack trace.

Comment: I'm looking at it in about 2 hours, and it does not say anything to me...
Function is working properly, location is showed on map. App crashes when I tap on map....

Comment: The stack trace will tell you exactly which line is throwing the error. Try putting a break point on the first line in the function that is failing. Press 10 to go to each line one at a time. Verify that the myPosition value is valid and has information and that the properties you are using are valid numbers.

Comment: If you mean "Line 112" - it points to `Debugger.Break();` in App.xaml.cs file. So it says nothing.